# Charging phones with lots of current

Tags: power-supply, power, current

My question is, what if I want to charge my iphone that uses 5volts via USB, however what if I had a powersupply that could deliver 5volts upto 10amps, if I used this to charge my phone would it ruin the phone? I thought that the phone only draws what it needs from the powersupply to charge it. Or would I be best to buy a charger to be used to charge my phone? Are phone chargers smart and turn off when phone is charged?

Answer (score 2):

Your phone will only draw as much current as it needs to charge the battery. The opposite situation, where a device wants to draw more current than the power supply can handle will be a bigger problem, as it may either overload the power supply or it will prevent you from charging properly. (Either not charging at all or with increased charge time as a result)